# ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'items') after using globalization

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I am trying to list the names of all the countries into a dropdown `using CultureInfo` of `system.globalization` by following an example.

Here is what I have in my controller

```
using System.Globalization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        List<string> CountryList = new List<string>();
        CultureInfo[] CInfoList = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures);
        foreach (CultureInfo CInfo in CInfoList)
        {
            RegionInfo R = new RegionInfo(CInfo.LCID);
            if (!(CountryList.Contains(R.EnglishName))) {
                CountryList.Add(R.EnglishName);
            }
        }

        CountryList.Sort();
        ViewBag.CountryList = CountryList;
        return View();
    }
```

And here is what I have in my dropdown list in my razor page

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("AddShipment", "Shipment", FormMethod.Post ))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
       <tr>
       <td>Country: </td>                  
       <td> @Html.DropDownList("CountryList",new SelectList(ViewBag.CountryList),new {@class = "form-control" })</td>
       </tr>
    </table>
}
```

Once I run the project, it says

```
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'items')
AspNetCoreGeneratedDocument.Views_Home_Index.ExecuteAsync() in Index.cshtml
 <td> @Html.DropDownList("CountryList",new SelectList(ViewBag.CountryList),new {@class = "form-control" })</td>
```

Can anyone tell me why is it giving me the error page?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I try your code, and I need to add `"using System.Collections.Generic;" `for  `List<string>` , it works fine. Which version of asp.net core do you use?

Comment: Try  to set the debug at `ViewBag.CountryList = CountryList;` to see the value of  `CountryList`.

Comment: `if (!(CountryList.Contains(R.EnglishName))) {...` <-- This is very inefficient because using `List<T>.Contains` in a loop is `O(n*m)`. Use a `HashSet<String>` instead.

Comment: `CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.SpecificCultures)` <-- Even though you're getting distinct `EnglishName` values, this **will not** give you a list of all the countries in the world; instead all you need is an in-memory collection that you can hard-code from a copy+pasted list like this gist I wrote: https://gist.github.com/Jehoel/942148c1f5dbe6d456a38c6d4a938525

Comment: Hi Qing, I have the newest version of .net

Comment: I do have `using System.Collections.Generic;` but it's not even using it and I am still having the same error.

Answer (score 1):

For dropdown list, the system expect a SelectList while you are passing List of string. This is the controller

```
 public IActionResult Index()
    {
        List<string> CountryList = new List<string>();
        var itemlist = new List<SelectListItem>();

        foreach (CultureInfo ci in CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.NeutralCultures))
        {
            if (!(CountryList.Contains(ci.EnglishName)))
            {
                CountryList.Add(ci.EnglishName);
                itemlist.Add(new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = ci.EnglishName,
                    Value = ci.EnglishName
                });

            }
        }

        var _CountryList = new SelectList(itemlist.OrderBy(x => x.Text), "Value", "Text",null);

        ViewBag.CountryList = _CountryList;

        return View();
    }
```

This is the View

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddShipmrnt", "Shipment", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>Country: </td>
            <td> @Html.DropDownList("CountryList",(SelectList)ViewBag.CountryList, "-Select-",new{@class ="form-control"})</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```

Comment: Do I keep what I have in the razor pages the same? and replace yours in the controller? Also, do I need to keep `CountryList.Sort();` ?

Comment: you don't have to change anything on the razor page. If u need to sort, perhaps you need to sort it before you add to the selectlistitem.

Comment: okay I am getting an errors and in `trans` `new SelectList()`

Comment: Answer edited. Typo error.

Comment: I still have errors on 1. `SelectList()` and 2. `CountryList` on your line 8. Do you not have the errors?

Comment: I didn't really test the code. Please try again.

Comment: The code runs now! but it still says `ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'items')` on the razor page. Am I using `DropDownList` wrong?

Comment: ok. This is a working code. I wrote it and tested it on my system. It should works and it takes care of the sorting as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249289/discussion-between-smbbb-and-yat-fei-leong).